# Running Mixtral 8x7B on Colab Free Tier and MacOS?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am trying to run Mixtral 8x 7B on Colab Free Tier and Mac (M3 PRO 36 RAM).
I ran the code from the [model page](https://huggingface.co/mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1) on Hugging Face, but I encountered an out-of-memory error. I am wondering if it's impossible to run such a large model due to the limitations of the free version of Colab and my Mac environment, or if there is another solution.

Here is the code I tried.

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

model_id = "mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id)

text = "Hello my name is"
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt")

outputs = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=20)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
```

After finishing downloading 19 safetensors, it starts loading checkpoint shards but stopped after 5%.